# C# selenium - WebDriver wait not waiting

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm using the Page Object model to design some selenium tests. I'm having a few issues with the wait code in my keywords below. When I call the keyword in my NUnit test using code such as below it trys to click on the button before it is ready. If I paste the same wait code in the NUnit test itself it waits as expected and then clicks the button. My preference would have all the keywords I implement to take care of the waits and not have to write it in my test. Am I missing something here?

NUnit Test

```
public void QuotesPageTest()
        {
             //Loginto CRM
            LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage();
            loginPage.UserLogin();

            //Select quotes tile
            pgCommon myMenu = new pgCommon();
            myMenu.GoToMenu("quotes");

             //Click new
            pgQuotes QuotesPage = new pgQuotes();        

            Keywords.DoSendKeys(QuotesPage.btnNew);           

         }
```

Keywords.cs

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TraingDay1_1
{
    public static class Keywords
    {
        public static void DoSendKeys(this IWebElement element)
        {
            String elementName = element.GetAttribute("value");
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(GlobalDriver.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(EnvironmentData.objectTimeout));            
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(element));
            element.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
            Console.WriteLine("Selected " + elementName + " and pressed enter key");

        }

        public static void DoClick(this IWebElement element)
        {
            String elementName = element.GetAttribute("value");
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(GlobalDriver.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(EnvironmentData.objectTimeout));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(element));
            element.Click();
            Console.WriteLine("Selected " + elementName + " and pressed enter key");

        }
```

Comment: Just guessing, but maybe there is a problem with driver? Check if the problem is when you use code: `public static void DoClick(this IWebElement element, IWebDriver driver).......WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(EnvironmentData.objectTimeout));` and call this method with driver from NUnit test class.

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint before this code gets run and step through it and make sure it's following the code path you expect. It looks good to me but I don't know if this is a simplified version of what you are really running.